# Php get last array key

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using this code to generate JSON string, but a faced with one problem, I try to find out is this the last element or not, I am using this `if(end($aData) != $aD)` but this is comparing the value, there is a problem,  when in the array are same values, How could I compare the $keys(get the last key and compare with the current key), or get the last element.

```
$ret    =   '[';
        foreach($aDatas as $aData)
        {
            $ret    .=  "{";
            foreach($aData as $key=>$aD)
            {               
                $ret    .=  '"'.$key.'":"'.$aD.'"';
                if(end($aData) != $aD)
                    $ret    .=  ',';
            }
            $ret    .=  "}";
            if(end($aDatas) != $aData)
                $ret    .=  ',';
        }
        echo $ret.']';
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it does anything special. Why don't you use the native [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode)?

Comment: why not use `json_encode()`? http://php.net/json-encode ?

Comment: because I didn't know this function, but now I know, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

May I suggest this PHP built-in function [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/json_encode)?

Might save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be to use the [`key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.key.php) function:

```
end($aData);
if(key($aData) != $key)
```

Comment: `end()` will move the array's internal pointer. Besides, `array_merge(array(1,2,1), array('foo','bar','quux'))`.

Comment: I had tried, but  I got the following error: key() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in

Comment: That would return the key of the last value of `$aData` or throw an error if that array element is no array.

Answer (score 1):

You know the size of the array. So simply increase a counter in every loop and then check if it's the last element.